# Uploaded html open as Google Document missing images

Tags: google-drive-api

Google Drive is not showing images on HTML Documents uploaded by both the Google Drive webpage and by the APIs.

I upload html file as well as images references in the html with relate page such as 
`<img src="/images/image1.png"/>` into /images subfolder.

When I open html file as Google Document on the drive, it's missing all images.  How do I make it include embedded images in the generated Google Document?